# Initializing a class retrieved by a function Java for android

Tags: java, android, class, methods

My first question on stackoverflow:

Ok so I am writing a java game for android and I am having trouble with initializing certain classes retrieved from a function/method. Here is my code:

```
static int unUsedCharacters = 10;
static Character char1;
static Character char2;
static Character char3;
static Character char4;
static Character char5;
static Character char6;
static Character char7;
static Character char8;
static Character char9;
static Character char10;

Character getFreeCharacter() {
        if (char1 == new Character()) {
            return char1;
        } else if (char2 == new Character()) {
            return char2;
        // and so on... until 10
        } else {
            return char10;
        }
    }

    public void createCharacter(String x) {
        if (unUsedCharacters > 0) {
            unUsedCharacters -= 1;
            getFreeCharacter() = new Warrior(); 
            //the warrior class extends the character class
        } else {
            /* no more characters */
        }
    }
```

So The problem is where I try to do:

```
    getFreeCharacter() = new Warrior();
```

It says:

> Variable expected.

Any suggestions?
(It is probarly super easy, but this is all new to me)

Thank you for reading/responding

Comment: Variable expected. 
That's what it says

Comment: You cannot initialize a method. That's why you're getting the error there. Also, you are doing `char1 == new Character()`, which will always return false. You are creating a new instance, and char1 does not already reference that instance. Therefore, `char == new Character()` will always return false

Comment: You do have such a problem, but not at the point you identify.  Perhaps it would help if you explain what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: Well the code has to initialize those characters given by the method.
And thank you all for answering so quickly!

Comment: Let me be clearer.  Your code is so broken that I cannot infer from it any details of what you intended it to do.  You have at least two fundamental misunderstandings here, and I cannot formulate a complete answer based on the information in front of me.  With that said, though, perhaps I should have asked specifically what the point of the `getFreeCharacter()` method is supposed to be.

Comment: Ok it is rather simple actually when you create a Character: you search for a free character slot (there are ten), when you have reached the max. amount of characters you can't make more ofc. and when you don't have enough money you can't either, the other names are the names of characters (gotten through inherrits or in java called extends of the class characters)

Comment: Well I made my code easier to understand ;-) might help you guys sorry for being so chaotic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression of this form...

```
 (char1 == new Character())
```

... will *always* evaluate to `false` (or throw an exception).  The `new` operator never produces a `null` result, and it never produces a reference to an object that existed before, but those alternatives cover all the possible values of `char1` at any time.  More likely you want something like this:

```
if (char1 == null) {
    char1 = new Character();
    return char1;
}
```

In truth, though, I would never hold the ten characters in ten independent variables.  I'd probably use a `List` of `Character`s, or at worst an array.

Having gotten past that, you have a different problem.  The `Character` you return is already an object assigned to the intended slot.  You can set its properties (to the extent that its class allows you to do so), but you cannot replace it with a different object by assigning to it.  Indeed, you cannot assign directly to the method result at all, but even if you stored it in a variable, assigning a different object to that variable would not have the effect you want.

(Note, by the way, that I am distinguishing between assigning to *members* of the method return value, which you can do, and assigning to the value itself, which you cannot do.)

I think you would be best off getting rid of `getFreeCharacter()` altogether.  If you structure your class better then you won't need it.  Instead of declaring `char1` ... `char10` like so:

```
// Yuck, don't do this
Character char1;
Character char2;
// ...
Character char1;
```

... do as I suggested earlier and use a `List`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public MyGame {

    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...

}
```

Then, your `createCharacter()` method can have this form:

```
public void createCharacter(String x) {
    if (characters.size() < 10) {
        characters.add(new Warrior()); 
    } else {
        /* no more characters */
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, you can retrieve elements of the character list via its `get()` method, e.g. `characters.get(0)`.  The `List` instance takes care of a whole lot of details that you will otherwise have to write your own code for.

Comment: Thanks for the list tip! but if I use this list, I'm having a new problem how do I remove those initialized characters again from the list?

Comment: Refer to the [List Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  In particular, you can use one of its `remove()` methods.

Comment: Now I am having the problem of removing certain list items, however this is a lot easier to understand! thank you! And that isn't part of this question anymore ;-).